# State loss occurring due to index change in ListView.builder on item deletion

Tags: flutter

I am using provider package for state management in my flutter app. I want to show multiple items in a list. For this, I am using the ListView.builder.
Whenever item is being deleted from the list at index i, the items occurring at index i+1 onwards are experiencing the state loss. On debugging, I see state is still there in provider but on UI, the data in those items clears out. For items before index i, there's no change occurring. So, need help with keeping state for items occurring after index i in the list.

Code for creating a provider

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ActivityListProvider())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Silver',
        theme: appTheme,
        home: PlanningPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the code for ListView.builder:

```
class PlanningPageState extends State<PlanningPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ActivityListProvider>(
      builder: (context, activityListProviderModel, child) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Plan'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: activityListProviderModel
                .cards.length, // Number of cards in the list
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var card = activityListProviderModel.cards[index];
              return ExpandableCard(
                key: ValueKey(card.id),
                id: card.id,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            activityListProviderModel.addCard();
          },
          tooltip: 'Add Item',
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for provider for state management:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:hello/src/activity_card_model.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class ActivityListProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<ActivityCard> _cards = [];
  var _uuid = Uuid();
  ActivityCard? dummyCard;

  List<ActivityCard> get cards => _cards;

  // Getter to find a card by UUID
  ActivityCard? getCardById(String uuid) {
    return _cards.firstWhereOrNull((card) => card.id == uuid);
  }

  void addCard() {
    var uniqueId = _uuid.v4(); // Generates a unique UUID
    _cards.add(ActivityCard(id: uniqueId));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateCard(String uuid, ActivityCard updatedCard) {
    var cardIndex = _cards.indexWhere((card) => card.id == uuid);
    if (cardIndex != -1) {
      _cards[cardIndex] = updatedCard;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void removeCard(String uuid) {
    _cards.removeWhere((card) => card.id == uuid);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Code to call removeCard:

```
IconButton(
            onPressed: () =>
                {context.read<ActivityListProvider>().removeCard(widget.id)},
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            ),
          ),
```

**Update**
Just realized I missed putting the code for reading from the state during build. It's working now.

Comment: How do you create the `ActivityListProvider`? How do you call `removeCard`?

Comment: Update question with code snippets for both.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code is not working but here is a simplified example code very similar to what you want to achieve. You can run it on `dartpad.dev`. I hope it helps.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ActivityListProvider())
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
          body: ActivityList(),
        )),
      );
}

class ActivityList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Consumer<ActivityListProvider>(
        builder: (context, activityListProvider, child) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Plan'),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: activityListProvider.cards.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final card = activityListProvider.cards[index];
                return Card(
                    key: card.key,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(card.key.toString()),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => context
                            .read<ActivityListProvider>()
                            .removeCard(card.key!),
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      ),
                    ));
              },
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => activityListProvider.addCard(),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class ActivityListProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Card> _cards = [];
  final _random = Random();

  List<Card> get cards => _cards;

  void addCard() {
    _cards.add(Card(key: ValueKey(_random.nextInt(100000000))));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeCard(Key key) {
    _cards.removeWhere((card) => card.key == key);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Just realized I missed putting the code for reading from the state during build. It's working now.